# Naive Bayes classifier performance is unexpected

Tags: machine-learning

I have just started using the Naive Bayes for text classification. I have coded it from the pseudo code snapshot attached.

I have two classes i.e. positive and negative. I have total of 2000 samples(IMDB Movie Reviews) out of which 1800 (900 positive, 900 negative) are used to train the classifier whereas 200 (100 negative, 100 positive) are used to test the system.

It marks the positive class documents but failed for classifying negative class documents propely. All documents belonging from negative classes are misclassified into positive class and thereby give accuracy of 50%.

If i documents from each class individually like first test all document belonging from negative classes and then from positive test samples then it give me accuracy of 100% but when i feed it mixed test samples it fails and classify all in one class (in my case positive).

Is there any mistake i am doing or is unavailable in this algorithm ?
Are training sample too less and classifier performance will increase upon increase training samples?

I have tested same samples with `weka` and `rapid miner` both are giving much better accuracy. I know that i have made a mistake but what is that i can't grab it ?Its the most simple one in understanding but accuracy result was totally unexpected and driving me crazy.Here is my code algorithm pseudo code. I have generating document vector using `tf-idf` for term weighting and document vector is used for calculations.

```
TrainMultinomialNB(C, D)

1.  V = ExtractVocabulary(D)
2.  N = CountDocs(D)
3.  For each c E C
4.  Do Nc = CountDocsInClass (D, c)
5.  Prior[c] = Nc/N
6.  Textc = ConcatenateTextOfAllDocsInClass (D,c)
7.  For each t E V
8.  Do Tct = CountTokensOfTerm(textc, t)
9.  For each t E V
10. Do condprob[t][c] = (Tct + 1) /(Sum(Tct) + |V|)
11. Return V, prior, condprob

ApplyMultinomialNB(C, V, prior, condprob, d)

1.  W = ExtractTokensFromDoc (V, d)
2.  For each c E C
3.  Do score [c] = log (prior)
4.  For each t E W
5.  Do score [c] + = log (condprob[t][c])
6.  Return argmax(cEC) score [c]
```

[image: algorithm]

Comment: Usually you take the `log` when computing the conditional probabilities. Maybe you are running to numerical problems.

Comment: I have tried that too i.e. in calculating conditional probabilities i have used <code> log(Tct + 1) - log (Sum(Tct) + |V|) </code> but result stays the same.